# Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects exactly 1 parameter, 2 given

Tags: php, html, mysqli, error-handling, syntax-error

I got a small issue... I have spend some time trying to create a mysqli login script, but is not doing anything than running into problems... I've tried multiple things, but gets an error every single time. Now I've come to a time where I can't solve my problems on my own anymore. The error I'm getting is

> Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, object given in D:- FTP- WEB- WEB 5.0\index.php on line 26

```
<?php  
   $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "testing");  
   session_start();  
   if(isset($_SESSION["username"]))  
   {  
       header("location:entry.php");  
   }  

   if(isset($_POST["login"]))  
   {  
       if($_POST["username"] == '' || $_POST["pin"] == '')  
       {  
            echo '<script>alert("Alle felter SKAL udfyldes!")</script>';  
       }  
       else  
       {  
           $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["username"]);  
           $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["password"]);  
           $pin = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["pin"]);  
           $password = sha1($password);  
           $pin = sha1($pin);
           $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username'";  
           $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);  
           if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)  
           {
                $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($connect, $result) ;
                $pass = $row['password'] ;
                $check_pin = $row['pin'] ;

                if ($password === $pass && $pin === $check_pin){
                   $_SESSION['username'] = $username;  
                   header("location:entry.php");
                }    
           }  
           else  
           {  
                echo '<script>alert("Forkert brugernavn, adgangskode eller pin-kode")</script>';  
           }  
      }  
 }  
 ?>
 <!DOCTYPE html>  
 <html>  
      <head>  
      <script>
      var loc = window.location.href+'';
if (loc.indexOf('http://')==0){
    window.location.href = loc.replace('http://','https://');
}
      </script>
           <title>
          MJVS - Private area.
           </title>  
           <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/title_logo.png" />
           <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>  
           <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />  
           <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  

      </head>  
      <body>  
           <br /><br />  
           <div class="container" style="width:500px;">  
                <h3 align="center"></h3>  
                <br /> 
                <h3 align="center"><b>Login</b></h3>  
                <br />  
                <form method="post">  
                     <label>Enter Username</label>  
                     <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" />  
                     <br />  
                     <label>Enter Password</label>  
                     <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" />  
                     <br />  
                     <label>Enter PIN</label>  
                     <input type="password" name="pin" class="form-control" maxlength="4" />  
                     <br />  
                     <input type="submit" name="login" value="Login" class="btn btn-info" />  
                     <br />   
                </form>  
                <?php       
                
?>
           </div>  
      </body>  
 </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php). The function takes one parameter. In particular, in the `$result` parameter in your case is

> Procedural style only: A result set identifier returned by mysqli_query(), mysqli_store_result() or mysqli_use_result()

You are giving it two. Only pass the result variable.

Breaking it down, you have:

```
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query)
```

where you get your result set (with `$link` representing your connection), and

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)
```

to get a generic row. The documentation itself has two examples.

Comment: I've tried with 1 parameter, nor still no success. 
New error: It will not log me in now.

Answer (score 0):

`mysqli_fetch_assoc` function require only one parameter(result set return by `mysqli_query` function).

Replace

```
mysqli_fetch_assoc($connect, $result);
```

with

```
mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
```

And read more about [mysqli_fetch_assoc](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php)

Comment: That does not work. I've tried it. It won't let me login with only 1 parameter, nor with 2 parameters...

Answer (score 0):

Can you use one parameter in "mysqli_real_escape_string" and let me know whether working or not?

Comment: I can't : That does not work. I've tried it. It won't let me login with only 1 parameter, nor with 2 parameters...

Comment: In the html , for each of the textbox and password field , add id attribute and give the same value what you have given for "name" attribute and let me know whether working or not

Comment: Did you made the changes and checked ?

Comment: I do not quite know how to exactly do that, unfortunately..... I'm not a programmer in daily